# How to work with a function preg_replace with a large number (1000000) of values in $patterns and $replacements arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, replace, preg-replace, large-data

**Hello dear programmers!** I'm having a **problem** with the speed of the function `preg_replace()`.

When I had **little** values (**words**) in the `$patterns` and `$replacements` arrays, the problem was not with the **speed** of searching and replacing **in text** from arrays, and when the number of the value in the arrays **increased by 1.000.000** then the function `preg_replace()` was repeatedly **slowed down**. How can I search and replace in the text if I have more than 1,000,000 values (words) in the arrays? How to make a replacement as **quickly** as possible? Can the solution of the problem be **buffered** or **cached**? What advise, how correctly to me to act?

Here is an example of my array:

```
$patterns = 
array
(
0 => "/\bмувосокори\b/u",
1 => "/\bмунаггас\b/u",
2 => "/\bмангит\b/u",
3 => "/\bмангития\b/u",
4 => "/\bмунфачир\b/u",
5 => "/\bмунфачира\b/u",
6 => "/\bманфиатпарасти\b/u",
7 => "/\bманфиатчу\b/u",
8 => "/\bманфиатчуи\b/u",
9 => "/\bманфиатхох\b/u",
10 => "/\bманфи\b/u",
...........................
1000000 => "/\bмусби\b/u"
)

$replacements =
array
(  
0 => "мувосокорӣ",
1 => "мунағғас",
2 => "манғит",
3 => "манғития",
4 => "мунфаҷир",
5 => "мунфаҷира",
6 => "манфиатпарастӣ",
7 => "манфиатҷӯ",
8 => "манфиатҷӯӣ",
9 => "манфиатхоҳ",
10 => "манфӣ",
.....................
1000000 => "мусбӣ"
);

$text = "мувосокори мунаггас мангит мангития мунфачир манфиатпарасти...";
$result = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $text);
```

> I use this javascript function in index.html file:

```
<script>
function response(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) { 
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "response.php?request=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

> PHP file response.php source:

```
<?php

$patterns = array();
$replacements = array();

$request = $_REQUEST["request"];

$response = "";

if ($request !== "") {

$start = microtime(true);

$response = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $request);

$stop = microtime(true);

$time_replace = $stop - $start;

}

echo $response === "" ? "" : $response."<br>Time: $time_replace";

?>
```

Comment: It's not clear how much it slowed down from your question. Did it slow down by 1 million times (which would be expected, doing 1 million more things), or by more than that?

Comment: This is a performance improvement question, right? -- not a busted code.  Isn't there another site for that?

Comment: I use a javascript function that uses the GET method to pass the textarea value to a php file that instantly corrects the word. The problem is that when I have more values in the array with replacements, the function preg_replace slows down a bit. Therefore, you need to somehow improve the speed of the function preg_replace. For example, when I enter the letter "a" in a textarea in HTML page, javascript fetches this letter using the GET method immediately into the php variable and processes it with the function preg_replace and back is passed.

Comment: I also do not know how slow the performance of the function was, but I simply did not measure it. Just could not measure when every input is passed all the information in the text field and is processed and returned.

Comment: It's a matter of improving performance, right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time complexity of your algorithm is roughly *O(nm)* where *n* is the number of words in your replacement array, and *m* the number of words in the request.

Since all the patterns seem to look for words (`\b` before and after), and don't use any other regular expression syntax (only literal characters) you will get better performance by splitting the request into words and looking them up in an associative array, without the need to use regular expressions at all.

So define your pattern/replacement data as an associative array, like this:

```
$dict = array(
    "мувосокори" => "мувосокорӣ",
    "мунаггас" => "мунағғас",
    "мангит" => "манғит",
    "мангития" => "манғития",
    "мунфачир" => "мунфаҷир",
    "мунфачира" => "мунфаҷира",
    "манфиатпарасти" => "манфиатпарастӣ",
    "манфиатчу" => "манфиатҷӯ",
    "манфиатчуи" => "манфиатҷӯӣ",
    "манфиатхох" => "манфиатхоҳ",
    "манфи" => "манфӣ",
    ...........................
    "мусби" => "мусбӣ"
);
```

Then use `preg_replace_callback` to find each word in the request and look it up in the above dictionary:

```
$response = preg_replace_callback("/\pL+/u", function ($m) use ($dict) {
    return isset($dict[$m[0]]) ? $dict[$m[0]] : $m[0];
}, $request);
```

The time complexity will be linear to the number of words in the request.

#### Handling upper/lower case

If you need to match also any variation in the capitalisation of the words, then it would be too much to store any such variation in the dictionary. Instead, you would keep the dictionary in all lowercase letters, and then use the code below. When there is a match with the dictionary, it checks what the capitalisation is of the original word, and applies the same to the replacement word:

```
$response = preg_replace_callback("/\pL+/u", function ($m) use ($dict) {
    $word = mb_strtolower($m[0]);
    if (isset($dict[$word])) {
        $repl = $dict[$word];
        // Check for some common ways of upper/lower case
        // 1. all lower case
        if ($word === $m[0]) return $repl;
        // 2. all upper case
        if (mb_strtoupper($word) === $m[0]) return mb_strtoupper($repl);
        // 3. Only first letters are upper case
        if (mb_convert_case($word,  MB_CASE_TITLE) === $m[0]) return mb_convert_case($repl,  MB_CASE_TITLE);
        // Otherwise: check each character whether it should be upper or lower case
        for ($i = 0, $len = mb_strlen($word); $i < $len; ++$i) {
            $mixed[] = mb_substr($word, $i, 1) === mb_substr($m[0], $i, 1) 
                ? mb_substr($repl, $i, 1)
                : mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($repl, $i, 1));
        }
        return implode("", $mixed);
    }
    return $m[0]; // Nothing changes
}, $request);
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/Hxoh)

#### Converting your existing arrays

You can use a little piece of code to transform your current *$patterns* and *$replacements* arrays to the new data structure, to avoid you have to do it "manually":

```
foreach ($patterns as $i => $pattern) {
    $dict[explode("\b", $pattern)[1]] = $replacements[$i];
}
```

Of course, you should not include this conversion in your code, but just run it once to produce the new array structure and then put that array literal in your code.

Comment: About your convertion: it isn't very interesting to convert two arrays with 1e6 items in an associative array. It is more useful to produce the php code that defines this associative array that can be pasted in the code once and for all.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, of course, the that script should only be used once to help convert the current structure into the new structure, and then have the code updated with that once and for all. Thanks for pointing out the typo! Corrected.

Comment: This method **not worked**! When, I enter to variable $response this text script dos'n convert it. <br>                                                             
**$request = "Ман мувосокори мувосокоримувосокори, мунағғас майлаш!";**

Comment: @Otabek, I don't have your complete dictionary, but at least the second word *is* replaced, as you can see [here on eval.in](https://eval.in/794640). The third word seems a concatenation of the same word twice. That will not work, because it is seen as one word, not as two. When you split the repeated word with a space, it works also: https://eval.in/794643

Comment: Yes, yes it works. Sorry that I ignored the code you wrote as not a working script. It turns out I had some error in my script.

Comment: But what about the **register** of words? For example, if the user enters the word **"мувосокори"** as **"Мувосокори"** or **"МУВОСОКОРИ"** or else **"муВосоКори"**. The answer should be exactly as it was written, that is, as **"Мувосокорӣ"**,**"МУВОСОКОРӢ"**,**"муВосоКорӣ"** using a single array of words in lowercase. Or do I need to create a separate array for each register of words? After all, this reduces the performance of the script.

Comment: I added a section in my answer that covers the treatment of words with mixed capitalisation.

Comment: Thank you dear Trincot. You make the part of my program much easier.

Comment: Hello @Trincot! Sorry that I'm still bothering you with your code. Now your function or code in the dictionary can save and replace only `one word` for another word. For example `точик => тоҷик`. And how is it possible to change it so that he can change by two words. Example `забони точик => забони тоҷик`? Or should I create a new question on this topic so that you can answer?

Comment: You cannot use this method for pairs of words, so yes, I suggest you ask a new question about this. Maybe someone else has a good idea. However, if you only have a few of those pairs, your original method could be used just for those cases only.

Comment: there are too many of them. I'll create a new question now and send for you link @trincot

Comment: You can see new question @trincot [link to question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46978603/how-to-make-the-function-work-for-pair-words)