# How to make the function work for pair words?

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, case-insensitive, preg-replace-callback

My function now only works with one word. For example, I have words in an associative array. And my function replaces the array key with its value in the text. And the function to keep the words in the lower case, but when you replace words it will return the incoming word register that is written on the text. Now the function can not work with pairs of words to replace pairs of words with other pairs of words.

### Example:

```
// Function:

function replaceKeyToValue($request, $dict){
    $response = preg_replace_callback("/\pL+/u", function ($m) use ($dict) {
        $word = mb_strtolower($m[0]);
        if (isset($dict[$word])) {
            $repl = $dict[$word];
            // Check for some common ways of upper/lower case
            // 1. all lower case
            if ($word === $m[0]) return $repl;
            // 2. all upper case
            if (mb_strtoupper($word) === $m[0]) return mb_strtoupper($repl);
            // 3. Only first letters are upper case
            if (mb_convert_case($word,  MB_CASE_TITLE) === $m[0]) return mb_convert_case($repl,  MB_CASE_TITLE);
            // Otherwise: check each character whether it should be upper or lower case
            for ($i = 0, $len = mb_strlen($word); $i < $len; ++$i) {
                $mixed[] = mb_substr($word, $i, 1) === mb_substr($m[0], $i, 1) 
                    ? mb_substr($repl, $i, 1)
                    : mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($repl, $i, 1));
            }
            return implode("", $mixed);
        }
        return $m[0]; // Nothing changes
    }, $request);
    return $response;
 }

    // Example associative array

    $dict = array
    (
      "make"=>"take",
      "cool"=>"pool",
      "узбек"=>"ӯзбек",
    );

    $text = 'Make COOL узБЕК';

    echo replaceKeyToValue($text, $dict);
```

#### Output:

```
Take POOL ӯзБЕК
```

How will the function be redone so that it can also pair words into pair words?

#### Example array with pairs words:

```
$array = array
(
  "take pool" => "pool take", 
  "get book" => "set word", 
  "узбек точик" => "ӯзбек тоҷик"
);

$example_text = "Take POOL Get BooK УзБеК ТоЧИК";
```

Comment: I [tried the code](https://3v4l.org/DA5OR) but I get `Make COOL узБЕК` as output.

Comment: if @WiktorStribiżew doesn't have an answer, there is no answer :)

Comment: The final `return` statement should read `return $response;`

Comment: What if you have `{ "A" => "ax", "B" => "bx", "A B" => "aa bb", "B A" => "x y" }` then what do you expect to become of the input "A B A B A B A"?

Comment: Try replacing the regex with `"/(?<!\w)(?:" . implode('|', array_keys($dict)) .  ")(?!\w)/iu"`

Comment: Do you know the general pattern? If you know it, you are there. If not, you will have to rely on the alternation based regex, but you may have issues with it if the `$dict` size is too large.

Comment: You just overwritten the returned variable `$response` about writing which I made a mistake and this is not an answer. You there used an array with odd words and I need to use an array with pairs of words to return the result. @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: Most likely I need to replace identical lines on length but pair words. For example `("аб аб" => "дт сд", "как так" => "ҷак ғак", "тар, тари" => "тар, тарӣ")` @trincot

Comment: @Otabek See https://3v4l.org/vqTNi, you misunderstood my hint, I guess (I can't understand [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46978603/how-to-make-the-function-work-for-pair-words?noredirect=1#comment80919423_46978603), sorry).

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. You can write an answer so I can mark it as an answer @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: I am in a rush now, I will post as soon as I can.

Comment: Ok, I'll wait your answer @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: Could you please let know the average dictionary size? I am afraid that the number of keys may be too high for a simple alternation approach. Note that the real solution will bea bit more complex since you seem to have no control  over the order of the dictionary items and might have `word` and `word word2` like terms to search for.

Comment: My vocabulary is very large (a minimum of 100,000 keys will be for the array) and tested and executed for 15-18 seconds for 2-3 sentences @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: Here, in the main, the correctness of the work and the speed of work are also necessary if possible. But it is possible or not, I do not know.

Comment: Please check https://3v4l.org/70DeD, the third opion - trie. If it is fast enough it is what you need.

Comment: Error: `preg_replace_callback(): Compilation failed: regular expression is too large at offset 363168`

Comment: When I use only the function itself, too, the error: `preg_replace_callback(): Compilation failed: regular expression is too large at offset 720525`

Comment: This is what makes such an error? @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: I still believe you need to use a regex TRIE, but there is a problem [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172837/regular-expression-is-too-large-error-in-php). You need to somehow remove the limit of the regex length. Or revamp the TRIE code to also perform replacement.

Comment: How to remove limit of the regex length? @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172837/regular-expression-is-too-large-error-in-php

Comment: `ini_set("pcre.backtrack_limit", "100000000");` ?

Comment: That is not the same as backtrack limit.

Comment: How to use `DEFINE` for shorten regex? @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: You can only do that if you repeat certain patterns in your regex. You cannot use this in the current scenario.

Comment: I can't revamp the TRIE code to also perform replacement or remove the limit. I have not yet stalked with such problems. @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: It all happens because of the big vocabulary huh? @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: What if I divide my vocabulary into parts and replace it in stages? For example, first I use the first part of the dictionary, then the second, the third, and so on @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: Yes, perhaps, it is a viable approach if you can easily subset the vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

First thing: push your case transformation out of the problem and write a dedicated function to handle it.

About the word pairs: You can solve the problem using:

- a lookahead with an optional subpattern to capture a second word
- a **static** boolean variable (defined in the callback function) to know if the previous match was the first word of an existing two words substring.

You only need this pattern:

```
~\b\pL+\b(?=( \pL+\b)?)~u
```

The lookahead allows to walk the string at each start of word (even at the end of the string since `(?=( \pL+\b)?)` is an *always true assertion*.) since it doesn't consume any character.

It's very simple:

- the boolean variable is set to `false` at the beginning.
- when the boolean is false and `$m[0].$m[1]` *in lowercase* exists in the dict keys, then set the boolean to `true` and return the dict value, else return `$m[0]`
- when the boolean is true, set it to `false` and return an empty string

Advantage: You don't have to take care about the dict size. Using the same idea, you can even extend the algorithm to more words with little changes or handle a dict in which items keys have a different number of words.

Advice: when you think to change the backtracking limit or to build a giant alternation, don't do it. It only means your approach isn't the good one.

Comment: Your template did not work for me. Or I could not correctly what you advised. Could I show you by updating your answer with an example using your template in my function using my dictionary and text? @Casimir et Hippolyte